# Sending part of the data to frontend and after clicking next pages sending another request to backend for the rest of it for efficiency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, ag-grid

I have a large dataset sometimes containing millions of products data. When I am sending it to frontend I limit it to 1000 product at first to be fast. This is how I am doing with Django rest:

```
def get_products(self, request, pk=None): 
        page = int(request.query_params['page']) if 'page' in request.query_params else 0
        page_size = 1000
        data = list(collection.find(filter_query, {'_id': 0}).skip(page * page_size).limit(page_size))
        total_count: collection.count()

       return Response({'message': 'success', 'data': data, 'count':total_count}, 200)
```

So in React, I accept the first 1000 products at first request. I show them on AG-GRID table. But I also need to show real page numbers ( I have the total count of the products). If user clicks on page=650 for example, I will send another request to the backend with the equivalent page number and fetch the remaining data.

```
            `http://localhost:8000/${ID}/products?page=${page}`
```

This is how I fetch data and show in AG grid on frontend:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        jwtAxios(
            `http://localhost:8000/${ID}/products/`  
            ).then((result) => {
            if (!result || !result.data.data || !result.data.data.length) {
                setRowData([]);
                setColumnData([]);
                return;
            }
            setRowData(result.data.data);

            // Get column fields
            const columnDefs = [];
            Object.keys(result.data.data[0]).map((fieldName) => {
                columnDefs.push({
                    headerName: fieldName,
                    field: fieldName,
                });
                return null;
            });
            setColumnData(columnDefs);
        });
    }, [catalogID]);

    // enables pagination in the grid
    const pagination = true;
    const paginationPageSize = 20;

    function imageCellRenderer(params) {
        return `<img alt="${params.value}" src="${params.value}" width="60px" height="80px">`;
    }
    return (
                <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={6}>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Paper className={classes.paper} elevation={1}>
                            <Grid
                                container
                                item
                                xs={12}
                                justify='center'
                                alignContent='center'
                                className={classes.previewTable}>
                                <div
                                    className='ag-theme-material'
                                    style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
                                    <AgGridReact
                                        defaultColDef={{
                                            editable: false,
                                            sortable: true,
                                            minWidth: 800,
                                            filter: true,
                                            resizable: true,
                                            enableBrowserTooltips: 'true',
                                        }}
                                        tooltipShowDelay={1}
                                        rowSelection='multiple'
                                        rowStyle={rowStyle}
                                        pagination={pagination}
                                        paginationPageSize={paginationPageSize}
                                        overlayLoadingTemplate={
                                            '<span className="ag-overlay-loading-center" style="padding: 10px; border: 2px solid #444; background: #fffef0;">Please wait while your data is loading</span>'
                                        }
                                        overlayNoRowsTemplate={
                                            '<span className="ag-overlay-loading-center"<span className="ag-overlay-loading-center" style="padding: 10px; border: 2px solid #444; background: #fffef0;">There is no data to preview</span>'
                                        }
                                        rowData={rowData}>
                                        {columnData.map((col) => {
                                            if (
                                                col.field.includes(
                                                    'image_link',
                                                ) &&
                                                !col.field.includes(
                                                    'additional',
                                                )
                                            ) {
                                                return (
                                                    <AgGridColumn
                                                        field={col.field}
                                                        minWidth={130}
                                                        tooltipField={col.field}
                                                        key={col.field}
                                                        cellRenderer={
                                                            imageCellRenderer
                                                        }
                                                    />
                                                );
                                            }
                                            return (
                                                <AgGridColumn
                                                    field={col.field}
                                                    minWidth={130}
                                                    tooltipField={col.field}
                                                    key={col.field}
                                                />
                                            );
                                        })}
                                    </AgGridReact>
```

I am not sure how to achieve that because AG grid only shows the pages according to the data from backend. Or is there a better way to show fast big data to frontend?  I couldn't find any source regarding this. Thanks.